# How to print an image to a MZ220 Printer from Android application?

Tags: android, printing, zebra-printers

I have a Zebra MZ220 portable Bluetooth printer.

currently i am able to print text/string on the printer through my android application using the following code...

```
private static void sendZplOverBluetooth(final String theBtMacAddress, final String Data) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                   ZebraPrinterConnection thePrinterConn = new BluetoothPrinterConnection(theBtMacAddress);
                   Looper.prepare();
                   thePrinterConn.open();
                   String zplData = Data;
                   thePrinterConn.write(zplData.getBytes());
                   Thread.sleep(500);
                   thePrinterConn.close();
                   Looper.myLooper().quit();
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
           }
       }).start();
```

}

I want to know if there is a way i can print an image on the printer through my android application, if so how? The image is stored on the SD card. Any assistance? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is! Check out the Developer demos that came developer demos that came with the SDK

```
<install_dir>\android\<version>\demos\src\com\zebra\android\devdemo\imageprint\ImagePrintDemo.java
```

Here is how you get a Bitmap:

> BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath())

and you can pass that to the printer via

> getGraphicsUtil().printImage(pathOnPrinter, bitmap, [x], [y])

Comment: that has to do with how your printer is configured to do a FormFeed. Something like this would only feed the paper 50mm after a print job:    ! UTILITIES<CRLF>
IN-MILLIMETERS<CRLF>
SETFF 50 2.5<CRLF>
PRINT<CRLF>.    See the SETFF command in the CPCL manual for more info.  Don't forget the <CRLF> (\r\n) The printer needs them to acknowledge commands. you get use the SDK to send commands. See getToolsUtil().sendCommand()

Comment: can you please send me the exact link for downloading the sdk of zebra ( jar file) and the demos ,i'm on Mac OSX

Comment: it's ok , i've asked a friend to install the exe sdk file and send me back the installed folder , and i've found the sdk , jar , demos , docs .. thanks anyway ;)

Comment: The new version has its own mac installer for the android stuff.  http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html